# Installing Network-x

Tags: networkx

How do I download and install network-x for python version 3.4.0 on mac? Can someone give me a step by step guide on installing network-x? I tried to quick 'quick install' as suggested by github. 
When I try to import it on python it gives me an import error saying no modules were found.

Comment: why not install it with `pip`?

Comment: I tried `pip install networkx` and then `pip install git://github.com/networkx/networkx.git#egg=networkx
`. Despite this, I still can't import it on python. Is there anything else that I have to do?

Comment: Try `pip -V` to see its version.  It may be linked to `python 2.7` not `python 3.x`.

Comment: Yes it is! How do I link it to python 3.x?

Comment: One simple way is to just use `pip3`. It is default installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ok so I have figured out an easier way:

**(Answering my own question)**

I first download the `networkx-1.10.zip (md5)` zip file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx. Unzipped it. Opened the terminal and typed `cd`

Then, I dragged and dropped the unzipped folder (`networkx-1.10`) into the terminal. Hit Enter.

Then I proceeded with the following commands:

```
python3 --version
ls
umask
sudo python setup.py install
sudo python3 setup.py install
python3
```

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

this has worked for me

```
sudo pip install networkx
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sudo pip3 install networkx
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have annaconda, in your terminal or cmd

```
> % conda install -c anaconda networkx
> % conda install -c anaconda graphviz
> % conda install -c anaconda pydot
> % conda install -c pdrops pygraphviz
```

The other packages come in handy as well

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), since networkX is installed by default. Just follow the instructions on their website (they have both a graphical and command line installer).